# Passing Entry Source DE External Key - Journey Builder Custom Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, custom-activity

I am developing a custom activity for JB. Is it possible to pass the Entry Source->Data Extension->External Key into inArguments to be used by the backend server?[image] [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the value of `_dataSourceName` in your email scripting:

```
%%[

var @dataSourceName
set @dataSourceName = AttributeValue("_datasourcename")

]%%
<br>@dataSourceName: %%=v(@dataSourceName)=%%
```

You can then [**record this in your Send Log**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/send-logging-data-sources/) as `dataSourceName` once you've set the variable.  It's not the the Customer/External Key, but it may serve your purpose.

Comment: From my experience, `_DataSourceName` in a journey context does not reflect the name of the entry source data extension but the name of the associated publication list (e.g. `All Subscribers`). To date, I haven't found any solution to dynamically retrieve the name of the entry source data extension from within a running journey.